# Iteration through a list with integers

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to build a python script that when given a Roman numeral converts it into an integer value.

I'm running into a problem when iterating through my input and trying to convert each letter to a variable which corresponds to a Roman numeral.

Here is the code:

```
I = 1
V = 5
X = 10
L = 50
C = 100
D = 500
M = 1000


# ask for user input
def numeral_value():
    entry = input('Enter a Roman Numeral \n')

    # if their input is only one character returns that character's value
    if len(entry) <= 1:
        newvalue = globals()[entry.upper()]
        print(newvalue)

    # now lets turn each list item into a variable
    else:
        newvalue = list(entry)

        i = int
        x = int

        for i in newvalue:
            globals()[i]

        # if list item is greater than the next iteration then simply adds each variable up and prints result

        for x in newvalue:
            if newvalue[x] < newvalue[x + 1]:
                multisum = newvalue[x] + newvalue[x + 1]
                print(multisum)


numeral_value()
```

As you can probably tell I'm a beginner so forgive me for the messy variable names.

When I run this the error I get is:

```
line 32, in numeral_value
    if newvalue[x] < newvalue[x + 1]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I don't understand why the interpreter views my list indices as strings when I previously ran globals() to turn each list index into an integer variable.

Thank you any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of `i = int`? You immediately overwrite the variable with `for i in newvalue:`. If you want to specify the type of a variable, use  `i: int`

Comment: The statement `globals()[i]` has absolutely no effect other than verifying that `i` is the name of a global variable.  It doesn't change the value of `i`, and it wouldn't do any good for it to change the value of `i` because that's just a local variable, with no connection to the list it came from.

Comment: Don't use `globals()` like that. Use dictionaries instead of dynamic variables.

Comment: The problem is here: ```for x in newvalue: if newvalue[x]``` - you can't reference list elements by a value in the list, only by a positional index. You need to look at the function `list.index()` and rethink your approach.

Comment: `for x in newvalue:` sets `x` to the elements of the list, not the indexes. Use `for x in range(len(newvalue)):` to iterate over indexes.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string

When you call `list()` on a string, it returns a list characters of that string, so `x in newvalue` is the characters that you've input.

To get the index as you iterate, you want to `enumerate`

```
for i, x in enumerate(newvalue):
    if newvalue[i] < newvalue[i + 1]:
```

But on the last iteration, `newvalue[i + 1]` will throw index out-of-bound error

---

Overall, I'd suggest starting with a dictionary, not `globals()`

```
numerals = {
'I' : 1
'V' : 5
'X' : 10
'L' : 50
'C' : 100
'D' : 500
'M' : 1000
}
```

Then replace `globals()[character]` with `numerals[character]` instead...

Also, your overall logic is missing subtracting, e.g. `IV` == 4, not 6